# What parameters should I use to measure storage I/O capabilities

Tags: sql-server-2012, performance, storage

I want to measure the throughput of my disk subsystem using: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DiskSpd-a-robust-storage-6cd2f223

what parameters should I use to closely emulate SQL I/O?

Is there a better tool/approach.

Problem I've got is that my SQL server keeps bogging down (few hundred users). I have no access to host. IT dept tell me it's not the host. They say they are SAS drives, but don't know if they are 10K or 15K. In Redgate monitor, I see disk I/O of 110MB sec. (AFAIK 15K SAS is only 126MB), so it seems to me that we're approaching max disk i/o and figured easiest thing to do is to run an I/O test on disk subsystem next time server is planned to be down

I also want to test our dev and staging because they run like molasses (restoring @ 5MB/sec) and agin IT dept say it's not the hosts.

TIA

Mark

Comment: Before diving too far into coming up with a decent response to your question (and the question behind it), I was hoping you could provide more information. You refer to "hosts" so I was wondering if this is a virtual environment. If so, can you please provide as much detail about your virtual environment as possible? e.g. Which virt. technology are you using? Are all machines ("guests") on the same host(s)? Are your hosts racked in the same enclosure as other hosts/physical servers?

Comment: For a good time, try Crystal Disk Mark: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-fast-your-san-or-how-slow/

Comment: @swascheck unfortunately (and staggeringly :-)) our IT dept can't even tell me (they outsource a bunch of stuff). I know they are all virtual machines (hypervisor I think)I think this vm has 8 cores and 114GB ram, but not sure how many other guest VM;s are on there. I know one other SQL VM shares the same storage subsystem

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik. thanks. Will try it on my dev instance (different storage subsystem)